# How to automatically select check box using selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, checkbox, selenium-ide

I am trying to create a code that automatically select one of the checkbox among five check boxes. What should I do for it? Is it possible to do so in Selenium IDE. If yes, please share code with me. Is there need to change/ edit in user extensions.js . If I want to create a function in user extensions for handling all check boxes is it possible? Kindly share with me both IDE and user extensions.js code for dealing such condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can select check box if different ways like mentioned below

```
1.click  name=abc
2.click  xpath=(//input[@name='vehicle'])
3.click  //input[@type='checkbox']
```

I hope you are looking for same.

Answer (score 1):

How to check a checkbox in Selenium IDE:

Force it to ALWAYS be on:

```
command: check
target: <locator>, id=my_checkbox, name=the_checkbox (or whatever you have)
value:
```

Force it to always be off:

```
command: uncheck
target: <locator>, id=my_checkbox, name=the_checkbox (or whatever you have)
value:
```

That's it.

Comment: Please don't include self-promotional links (or any links, for that matter), which do not directly address the *specific* question being asked. To do so (*especially* without disclosure of your affiliation with the link) exposes you to being flagged as a spammer.

Comment: Be aware that javascript event handlers may be linked to the **click events**. Using the chech/uncheck commands will not trigger those events (at least not in Firefox) and thus testing results may be different.

Comment: @R.Schreurs - true but using click as a command on its own does not guarantee the state of the checkbox.   For both you may want to first use the inverse, uncheck <id>, then click <id> to ensure the box is both checked and the click event is triggered.  You'll also find corner cases for keypress and other event-related triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can select the check box through Selenium ide

```
command: check
target:  id , name or Xpath of the check box (or whatever you have)
value :
```

Second  solution, you can used click command

```
command: Click
target:  id or Xpath of the check box (or whatever you have)
value
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only check at a specific checkbox using "clickAt" command and its Xpath.